# Converting jQuery Flot graph to pdf

Tags: jquery, pdf, flot

I tried almost to convert flot graph canvas to jpeg. But it gives only graph image not a legends present in the graph and i dont know how to bring it in to pdf. Please help me to come out from this..

Thanks in advance,
gaUti.

Answer (score 0):

The following affirmation is present on jQuery Flot's page "Flot is a pure JavaScript plotting library for jQuery", which means it is a pure client-side technology.

Pure client side technology don't have (direct) access to persistent storage (neither the visitors own filesystem nor the servers).

### Normal workflow - assumes you are targeting any browser

- Apache(+PHP) serves HTML page + JS scripts.
- JS scripts build the visual elements of the canvas which are present in the visitors browser memory.
- JS sends (via GET or POST) structural info to Apache(+PHP) server.
- Apache(+PHP) server analyses the structural info and builds a (? binary) PDF file based on the info and then sends the newly constructed PDF file to the visitors browser.
- The visitors browser triggers a "download a file" dialog.

---

### Possible workflow - assumes you are targeting modern browsers (IE > vs.9) which implement FileReference & FileAPI

- Apache serves HTML page + JS scripts.
- JS scripts build the visual elements of the canvas which are present in the visitors browser memory.
- JS scripts build a (? binary) file  server analyses the structural info and builds a PDF file based on it then sends the newly constructed PDF file to the visitors browser.
- JS scripts trigger a "download a file" dialog (using FileAPI).

Answer (score 0):

I already commented on your other question but it may be helpful here, too.

Have a look at the Flot Canvas Text plugin to render everything into the plot canvas:
http://lessaworld.com/projects/flotCanvasText/